# How to listen to beacons(broadcaster) using the simple_observer example?

Tags: embedded, bluetooth

I am using the TICC2640 for this purpose.

I am trying to use the **simple_observer** example from the SDK to listen to beacons. I am able to scan the devices and print their MAC addresses. I am broadcasting the beacon via an Android app called the "**locate beacon**". The example scans up to 8 devices while printing their MAC addresses. I have slightly modified it to now print the event type and address type as well as shown below.

```
// Display the indexed scanned device.
Display_print1(dispHandle, 2, 0, "Device %d", (scanIdx + 1));
Display_print0(dispHandle, 3, 0, 
Util_convertBdAddr2Str(devList[scanIdx].addr));
Display_print1(dispHandle, 4, 0,"addrType: %d",devList[scanIdx].addrType);
Display_print1(dispHandle, 5, 0,"eventType: %d",devList[scanIdx].eventType);
```

**Issue-1:** Among the scanned 8 devices, none of them is the device(my phone) that is broadcasting the beacon. This I have cross-checked with the displayed MAC address. How do I get this example to scan for the device that is broadcasting (beacon)?

**Issue-2:** I need to listen to the beacon packet and parse it for some purpose. However, from the above, I am not able to get the beacon to do anything with it.

There also seems to be no example or any such starting point when it comes to seeing beacons using this example. Is there any piece of code or specific configuration that can help me achieve the this?

Any support with the above would be appreciated.

Comment: This is going to be hard for anyone to answer without more detail.  Perhaps you should put the device and phone in a shielded box, or go somewhere that is non-urban, or modify the program to display everything and not only 8.

Comment: are you sure that the Android app is a beacon?  .... `locate beacon` sounds like it is a beacon locator ........... please provide as much relevant information as possible .... link to the SDK or to `simple_observer` would be useful